# What is this widget in Qt called?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am looking for a widget, but I don't know what the name of it is. It's a number field with little arrows on the side. When you click an arrow, the number will either increase or decrease. What is this widget called? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[QSpinBox](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html).

There is a [widget gallery](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/gallery-plastique.html) as part of the official documentation.

Comment: Yup. Did not know about the widget gallery. Thanks!

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the [`QSpinBox`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html) widget?